C# Dependency Injection from inheritence
Ive seen perviously the implementation of without explicitely injecting interface, when creating an interface can simply inherit for example Interface "IamContainerRegistered" and on compile it will inject the interface
Sorry i have no code to provide im not sure on where to start but help is appreciated.
So in pseudo its kind of like, For each interface which has been inherited by IAmContainerRegistered:
builder.RegisterType<ClassName>().As<InterfaceName>().InstancePerRequest();

(Using AutoFac)
So lets say for example i have ITest1 : IAmContainerRegistered ... ITest2 : IAmContainerRegistered
And this will produce:
   builder.RegisterType<Test1>().As<ITest1>().InstancePerRequest();
   builder.RegisterType<Test2>().As<ITest2>().InstancePerRequest();


Sorry, AutoFac .. updated to add into question

So, you have some interface called IamContainerRegistered, then a lot of other interfaces inherited from this one? Such as ITest1: IamContainerRegistered{}, ITest2: IamContainerRegistered{} and so on? And you want to register them all?

Hi please see updated question with my example logic, This has been done before using simple injector at a previous workplace but didnt see how the logic behind it worked.

You can use assembly scanning and filtering to get all types implementing the IAmContainerRegistered
var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
  
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(asm)
    .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<IAmContainerRegistered>())
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();

var c = builder.Build();

var t1 = c.Resolve(typeof(ITest1)); //Test1
var t2 = c.Resolve(typeof(ITest2)); //Test2
var unwanted = c.Resolve(typeof(IAmContainerRegistered)); //Test2

Disadvantages: the AsImplementedInterfaces() used instead of explicit interface name, so the IAmContainerRegistered interface will be also registered (see unwanted resolution in the sample.
